# Login para acceder a diferentes sistemas MVC. ¿Cómo traspasar datos y manejar la navegación?

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, mvc, login

Mi consulta es la siguiente: Tengo de momento 2 sistemas en c# MVC (serán más en total) y la idea es que puedan utilizar un mismo login. Dentro del login se pueden elegir los sistemas disponibles (según privilegios de usuario).

Hasta ahí todo bien, según creo. El botón de ingreso a cada sistema envía por Ajax un JWT con la info del usuario a un controlador del otro sistema, que carga los datos y asume el "login".

El problema es que no logro redireccionar al nuevo sistema. Al jecutar todos los proyectos desde visual studio y tener todas las ventanas abiertas (localhost:0001-->login // localhost:0002-->sistema2) puedo ver como el "sistema2" inicia sesión y me dirige a la pagina de inicio del usuario, pero esto no ocurre al publicar el sistema2, ya que la ventana  esta cerrada y no ocurre ningún cambio.

Probé con redireccionar en el "On Success" del metodo AJAX que envia la info desde el login, pero al parecer nunca ingresa pese a tener un status 200.

No sé si hay aguna forma de hacer esto directamente desde el backend y conectar ambos controladores, sería lo ideal, creo. Espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Asi es puedes hacer un servicio web-api de autenticacion y autorizacion para todos tus sistemas, en cada una de tus aplicaciones puedes agregar oauth para redireccionar al login cada que no estes firmado, Por lo pronto estudia un poco de OpenId y Oauth2.

Comment: Saludos Francisco, revisa "Identity Server". También revisa cómo preguntar: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask y realizar el recorrido: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que veas el funcionamiento del sitio. Ambos enlaces te ayudarán a elaborar mejor preguntas que tendrás mejor aceptación en el sitio :D

Comment: Gracias por su apoyo. A estudiar un poco y comento la solución.